# Entity Framework 6 adding extra inherited column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have the class `PERTActivity_T` which inherits from `MetadataTyper` class, so as other tables.

Opposite to its siblings `PERTActivity_T` already has the properties:

```
[ForeignKey("BSContext")]
public int? BSContextId { get; set; }
public BSContext BSContext { get; set; }
```

But now I need all tables that inherit from `MetadataTyper` to have those properties as well. So I removed them from `PERTActivity_T` and included them in `MetadataTyper` but when I generate a migration it removes the relationship from `BSContextId` to `BSContext` and adds an extra field called `BSContext_Id` (with an underscore) and adds the foreign key to it.

This happens only for `PERTActivity_T` the other tables that inherit from `MetadataTyper` migrate fine.

At first I tried to edit the migration manually to remove all changes to `PERTActivity_T` since it is already created the way I need it, it all seamed to work fine but when I use a mapper to edit `PERTActivity_T` or any table related to it EF throws an error saying `BSContext_Id` is unknown.

How can I make EF understand that `PERTActivity_T` doesn't need any additional changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was that `BSContext` already contained a navigation property to `PERTActivity_T` and then I duplicated it.

All I had to do was remove the duplicated navigation property and the migration generated fine.